# How ldap servers are queried by CAS?

Tags: ldap, cas

I have configured multiple LDAP servers. How is CAS querying them? Sequentially or in parallel? I want to build a hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, CAS will go through them sequentially as [described here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.3.x/installation/Configuring-Authentication-Components.html) until conditions (usually set in the service file) are met at which time it will stop and fulfill the request.